# Can Tableau do impersonation when connecting to Drill?

Tags: authentication, impersonation, apache-drill, tableau-api

I have Tableau Server connecting to a Drill view. I want to deal with authorisation in Drill so I need Drill to know who is requesting the data from Tableau Server. For this I need impersonation to work as otherwise session_user in Drill will always be Tableau Server service account and not an actual person connecting to Tableau Server.

This link seems to suggest that impersonation in Tableau works only for SQL Server:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.1/server/en-us/impers_requ.htm

It would be strange considering how many datasources Tableau supports... Is it really not possible? And if it is not, are there any workarounds?

My versions are: Tableau 10.1 and Drill 1.10

Comment: no luck with this?

Comment: No. We are now trying to test Sorabh's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion here because of Tableau doesn't mention about Drill anywhere in documentation. You can treat Drill as a SQL server and use impersonation with it. Drill supports something called [inbound impersonation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-inbound-impersonation/) which allows a connection user (session_user) in drill to impersonate a Tableau end user. The corresponding parameter for connection string of Drill is delegation_uid.